# access static resource with new keyword in java

Tags: java

I was using `OkHttpClient` [here](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). For using `get` request there was a below mentioned code that I was not able to understand :

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .build();
```

Here, I am not able to understand `new Request.Builder()`
I think we are accessing static `Builder()` method with `Request` class name. But if it is so, then why are we applying `new` keyword with  it?

Comment: What is OkHttpClient?

Comment: http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Comment: So I don't understand what prevented you from having a look at https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Request.java where you clearly see in line 100 what you were after.

Comment: @mannedear: It's the successor to SoSoHttpClient, which in turn was a fork that improved on RubbishHttpClient. But what you really want is the new fork, ReallyQuiteGoodHttpClient. </humour> ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that it looks like you are accessing a method that starts with capital letter. But **No**. It is not. `Builder()` is not a method. It is inner class of Ok HttpClient and you need outer resource reference to access inner class.

```
public static final class OkHttpClient.Builder
extends Object
```

---

From [source](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.java)

```
public static final class Builder {
    Dispatcher dispatcher;
    @Nullable Proxy proxy;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that library, so I am answering on a generic level.

If the syntax you use is correct, `Builder` is not a method of `Request`, but a (public and static) inner class. In this case, it is absolutely correct to do `new Request.Builder()`.

You create an object of this class, which lets you assemble the request as you need it and builds it then.

Answer (score 2):

**I hear you. java is not expressive.**

try writing the code this way

```
Request.Builder requestBuilder= new Request.Builder();

Request request=requestBuilder.url(url) //other attributes
      .build();
```

this is a famous creational design pattern in programming called [builder pattern](https://jlordiales.me/2012/12/13/the-builder-pattern-in-practice/).

> intention of the builder pattern is to find a solution to the telescoping constructor anti-pattern that occurs when the increase of object constructor parameter combination leads to an exponential list of constructors. Instead of using numerous constructors, the builder pattern uses another object, a builder, that receives each initialization parameter step by step and then returns the resulting constructed object at once.

Comment: The code you provide doesn't have any benefit over what is written in the question. Essentially, the answer starts woith the "this is a famous…", which is quite a good answer. But the start is not necessary.

Comment: thank you for the feedback.I really appreciate it.I will try to improve my later answers.I just wanted to put him in the picture.when I faced this at first it was overwhelming and I prefered for a long time to make this detailed lazy creation

Answer (score 1):

Here Builder is a static inner class of Request class that's why we use this syntax.

Comment: SubClass is different from Inner Class.